# A complex-valued function with a pole in $0$ cannot be bijective from $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ into $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

**Problem:**

Suppose we have $f :\mathbb{C}-\{0\} \to \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ defined as follow:

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{z^n} g(z)$$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ where $g$ is an holomorphic function in the whole $\mathbb{C}$ such that $g(0) \neq 0$ and where we assume $n$ is an integer $n \geq 2$.

Can we conclude that $f$ is not bijective from $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ to $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$?

If $n=1$ can we conclude that $g$ is necessarly costant and so $f(z)=\frac{a}{z}$ for $a \in \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$?

**My attempt:**

I tried to transform the problem in this way.

Defining $h_a(z)=az^n-g(z)$ for each $a \in \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$, I tried to prove that $h_a(z)$ has necessarly more than one zero in $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ ($h_a(0)=-g(0) \neq 0$ thus we can work in $\mathbb{C}$).

I tried to use Residue Theorem in order to study the integral:

$$\int_{\Gamma} \frac{h_a'(z)}{h_a(z)}dz=Z_a$$

where we define $Z_a$ as the number of zeros of the functions $h_a$ in the interior of the compact $\Gamma$ which is opportunely chosen.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, what about $z \mapsto z^{-1}$...?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 I tried with it too, but I cannot reach any conclusion. Do you have any idea?

Comment: It seems to be a counterexample to your claim. It satisfies the hypotheses yet is bijective. (Admittedly, I only have a bit of complex analysis knowledge, so forgive me if there’s something I’m missing)

Comment: In that example, $n=1$ and $g(z) = 1$.  Yes, it is a counterexample.  Now, if we say $z \ge 2$, then $f$ will not be bijective.

Comment: You are right, I will edit the question.

Comment: @GEdgar Do you mean $n \geq 2$? If yes, how can I prove it?

Comment: Yes $n \ge 2$.  You are on the right track above.  Near $0$ your function will be $n$-to-$1$ and not injective if $n \ge 2$..

Comment: @GEdgar Thank you very much, I will try again.